# Missing blank line under code snippet with scroll bar

Tags: bug, design, code-formatting, markdown-rendering, horizontal-scroll-bar

I've only just noticed this.  I am not sure if it used to happen before, and I have only just noticed it, or it is something that is new.

Check [the answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4116/does-anyone-know-how-slic3r-determines-its-infill-adjacent-strand-spacing-inste/4124#4124) to the question, [Does anyone know how Slic3r determines its infill adjacent strand spacing, instead of using fill density?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4116/does-anyone-know-how-slic3r-determines-its-infill-adjacent-strand-spacing-inste)

Looking at the screen shot below:

> [image: Screenshot of blank line under code snippet (without scroll bar) and no blank line under code snippet (with scroll bar)]

The text under the first code snippet (which had no horizontal scroll bar) is nicely spaced, with a blank line between the snippet and the next paragraph.

The text under the second code snippet (which has a horizontal scroll bar), is much more tightly "bunched up" to the bottom of the snippet. There is no (or not much of a ) blank line between the second snippet and the start of the following paragraph.

It appears that the additional horizontal scroll bar is taking the space provided by the blank line.

It would be nice if the snippet with the scroll bar, provided an additional blank line, somehow.

As an update, it is particularly bad if a horizontal bar follows a code snippet, the scroll bar and horizontal bar almost merge:

> [image: Horizontal bar, after a code snippet]

#### Version Info

Happens on Chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit), and Safari 6.2.8, on OS X 10.8.5

Firefox 48.0.2 and Opera 37.0 are OK though.

Hmm... could be caused by *out of date* browsers...

Comment: What browser is this?

Comment: @JasonC - It occurs on Chrome and Safari (which are out of date), but not on Firefox and Opera (which appear to be up to date). This is a possible *user error*. Sorry.

Comment: I can inly repro on Safari, not Chrome or anything else

Comment: No repro on Chrome 58, IE11, and Firefox 53 (all Windows), and Android Chrome (god knows what version).